# Issues with beautifulsoup.find() in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, stockquotes

I am trying to make a simple web scraper with python to get stock data. My code was working not long ago and I don't believe I changed anything but now I'm getting the following error:

> File `"tradingProgram.py"`, line 69, in 
>       `dataArr.append(i.find('div',{'class':'tv-screener-table__symbol-right-part'}).find('a').text)`
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

This is the part of the code that handles beautifulsoup:

```
content = requests.get("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-gainers/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text,'html.parser')
stockData = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row'})
print(len(stockData))

for i in stockData:
    print(i)
    dataArr.append(i.find('div',{'class':'tv-screener-table__symbol-right-part'}).find('a').text)
```

Comment: confirm `tv-screener-table__symbol-right-part` exist in page source

Comment: @0m3r awesome thanks!